# Unable to set the CUDA_HOME environment variable within Docker

Tags: docker, pytorch, dockerfile

I am using the pytorch/pytorch:1.11.0-cuda11.3-cudnn8-runtime Docker image as my base. While the image seems to be working fine and nvidia-smi is functional within the container.

```
# nvidia-smi
Tue Sep  5 11:31:06 2023       
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 535.104.05             Driver Version: 535.104.05   CUDA Version: 12.2     |
|-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                 Persistence-M | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                      |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1660        On  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 27%   33C    P8               5W / 120W |     46MiB /  6144MiB |      4%      Default |
|                                         |                      |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                                         
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                            |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                            GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                             Usage      |
|=======================================================================================|
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I've have `EnvironmentError('CUDA_HOME environment variable is not set. ' OSError: CUDA_HOME environment variable is not set. Please set it to your CUDA install root.`

I want to set the CUDA_HOME, but I don't know where the image has installed CUDA. I can't find it in the local folder. Could you please guide me? How can I resolve this error?

```
# ls /usr/local/
bin  etc  games  include  lib  man  sbin  share  src
```

p.s: I need PyTorch 1.11 and CUDA version higher than 9.2.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible because cuda is installed by conda in these image. And unfortunately giving this path as CUDA_HOME didn't solve the problem.

```
$ find / -type d -name cuda 
/opt/conda/pkgs/pytorch-1.11.0-py3.8_cuda11.3_cudnn8.2.0_0/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/cuda
/opt/conda/pkgs/pytorch-1.11.0-py3.8_cuda11.3_cudnn8.2.0_0/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/c10/cuda
/opt/conda/pkgs/pytorch-1.11.0-py3.8_cuda11.3_cudnn8.2.0_0/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/native/cuda
/opt/conda/pkgs/pytorch-1.11.0-py3.8_cuda11.3_cudnn8.2.0_0/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/cuda
/opt/conda/pkgs/pytorch-1.11.0-py3.8_cuda11.3_cudnn8.2.0_0/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/backends/cuda
/opt/conda/pkgs/pytorch-1.11.0-py3.8_cuda11.3_cudnn8.2.0_0/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/cuda
/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/cuda
/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/c10/cuda
/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/native/cuda
/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/cuda
/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/backends/cuda
/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/cuda
```